# Alias definition in Spring Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration-files, spring-java-config

My project depends on a dependency.jar artifact. The dependency contains a Spring service:

```
@Service
public class Service { }
```

In my project I inherit from the service and override some functionality:

```
@Service
public class MyService extends Service {
    // overriding
}
```

In Spring XML configuration I define alias to use MyService over Service everywhere:

```
<alias name="myService" alias="service" />
```

How to do alias definition in Spring Java configuration? Currently I do it this way, but it is not very elegant:

```
@Bean(name = "service")
public Service service(@Qualifier("myService") Service projectImplementation) {
    return projectImplementation;
}
```

Is there a better way how to do it in Spring Java configuration? Thank you!

Comment: You are on the right path. There is an open bug related to this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6736. What your doing looks okay.

Comment: Along with the answers, another approach is to wrap `MyService` in a proxy, with the proxy being injected.  This resolves the naming issue but perhaps more importantly hides the use of `Service` from dependency.jar.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide several aliases while declaring a bean:

```
@Bean({"myService", "service"})
```

According to the `name` attribute documentation:

> The name of this bean, or if several names, a primary bean name plus aliases.
>
> If left unspecified, the name of the bean is the name of the annotated method. If specified, the method name is ignored.
> The bean name and aliases may also be configured via the value attribute if no other attributes are declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value attribute of @Service annotation & give your alias name there like -

```
@Service ("service")
public class MyService extends Service {
    // overriding
}
```

And while autowiring or injecting use the alias given in value attribute like -

```
@Controller ("controller")
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("service")
    private MyService service;
}
```

This way you don't have to give alias name separately.